# SetError in Edittext is not fully visible when virtual keyboard apperars (but it works fine in xhdpi devices)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

I ve implememted a setError function for an edittext and is works fine in the xhdpi devices but when it comes in the matter of ldpi , hdpi or mdpi devices it works fine if the virtual keyboard is not comes in. but when the virtual key board come to the screen the Error message is not fully visible the last 1 or 2 word of the error message gets disappeared. any idea how is that happening...??

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your activity in manifest file

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try requestFocus on the textView or editText on which you are using setError.
Hope this works.
Also try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` ,this will make your screen stretch down when keyboard opens.

Comment: Actually I ve Multiple edittext with error Message in a screen itself and is the error message is visible for the edittext which has the focus . I ve given android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" for the activities so the key board wil not show up when the activity is loaded . it loads only when i touch on any of the edittext. then the message parts are missing.